# Call RaisedPropertyChanged for Parent Class when Child Property Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

## Structure of Program

Currently I am using the MVVMLight 4.1 framework in my application.

I have a view model `XViewModel` which wraps around an instance of `XClass`, `X`. `X` contains many properties such as `S`. I also have another instance of `XClass` in another ViewModel.

#### ViewModel

```
public XViewModelClass XViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public XClass X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        set
        }
            if(value == x)
            {
                return;                 
            }
            var oldValue = x;
            x = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(XPropertyName, oldValue, x, true)
        }

    }
    private XClass x;
    public const string XPropertyName = "X"
}
```

### ViewModel2

```
public YViewModelClass YViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public YViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<XClass>>(this, message =>
        {
            X2 = message.NewValue
        });
    }

    public XClass X2
    {
        get
        {
            return x2
        set
        }
            if(value == x2)
            {
                return;                 
            }
            var oldValue = x2
            x2= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(X2PropertyName)
        }

    }
    private string x2;
    public const string XPropertyName = "X2" 


}
```

### Model

```
public class X : ObservableObject
{
    public string S
    {
        get
        {
            return s;
        set
        }
            if(value == S)
            {
                return;                 
            }

            s = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(SPropertyName)
        }

    }
    private string s;
    public const string XPropertyName = "S" 
}
```

## Problem

How do I ensure that when any property in `X` changes (e.g. `S` is set to a different value), `RaisePropertyChanged` is called for `X`. It would be best if I don't have to send a property changed message for every property in my model.

The reason behind is that I have another instance of `XClass`, `X2' in another ViewModel and I want to keep both instances in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Proximo,

Can you provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish by firing a PropertyChangedEvent for X when a child member is set? Typically in WPF you be concerned
only with raising that event for the property/backing field to which you are bound, in this case X.S. Is there a specific use case for being notified when a member of X is set outside of scenario I provided?

Comment: I have another instance of XClass in another view model that I keep updated by using the RaisePropertyChanged method overload to raise a PropertyChanged message and registering to receive the mssage in the other viewmodel.